ROS2 procederal programming not oop
i have to port a huge Software (ca. 20000 lines of Code) from ROS1 to ROS2. Is it possible to use ROS2 not oop? It would be much easier for me to port it, otherwise i would have to programm it from the scratch because of the actual Software. The ROS1 Software was not programmed oop style. So is it possible with ROS2 to programm without oop?
Thank you.

yes it is possible. Obviously you'll need to make all the changes re: datatypes etc. But that is par for the course moving from ROS to ROS2.
You could find a 1/2 way house by creating classes with static members/methods?
Some examples here:
https://nu-msr.github.io/navigation_site/lectures/node_structure.html
Mark

Ok, thank you for your quick Answer. I will try it non oop.
